# Nose complaining in Python 3 but not 2

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I wrote tests using Python's `unittest` framework and ran them using Nose in Python 2.7 on Win7 x64 and they work fine:

```
D:\Users\Nick\Local HG\Waldo\code\shared\collider>py -2 -mnose
.............
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 13 tests in 0.039s

OK
```

However, when I run them under Python 3.4, I get an inexplicable error

```
D:\Users\Nick\Local HG\Waldo\code\shared\collider>py -3 -mnose
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ValueError ('D:\\Users\\Nick\\Local HG\\Waldo\\code\\shared\\__init__.py\\__init__.pyw\\__init__.pyc' is
 not a package)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nose\failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\imp.py", line 245, in load_module
    return load_package(name, filename)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\imp.py", line 210, in load_package
    raise ValueError('{!r} is not a package'.format(path))
ValueError: 'D:\\Users\\Nick\\Local HG\\Waldo\\code\\shared\\__init__.py\\__init__.pyw\\__init__.pyc' is not a package

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

My package structure is:

```
collider\
  |- tests\
  |    |- __init__.py
  |    |- test_removing_chains.py
  |
  |- __init__.py
  |- collider.py
  |- viz.py
```

I don't know where the "...`\\__init__.py\\__init__.pyw\\__init__.pyc`" bit is coming from in the error, or why it's even going up a folder (`\collider` gets axed from the path apparently) even though I'll run the program in either the package root or from within the `\tests` folder (same error).

Comment: [pep420](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), regarding python 3.3, includes the sentence "Namespace packages cannot contain an `__init__.py`." I'm not 100% familiar with the distinction between a 'regular package' and a 'namespace package', but I suspect that the `__init__.py` file in your tests and/or root directory may be causing the problem. Maybe try moving them and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing superfluous `__init__.py` and `.pyc` files up a couple paths as suggested the problem went away.

Unfortunately, however, I removed a bunch at once and adding them back in one-by-one didn't recreate the problem so I couldn't isolate what was the key point of failure.